# Report Viewer Configuration Error when upgraded from vs 2008 to vs 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, reportviewer

I have been assigned the task of upgrading our website from VS 2008 to VS 2013. I have come across several stumbling blocks on the way. I have upgraded the project from .Net 2.0 to 4.0 and the site runs fine except for the fact I get the following error when trying to view a report (the report itself does not display) :

**Report Viewer Configuration Error**

> The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in
>   the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers
>   section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers
>   section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

Some reports have been converted by selecting the report in VS 2013 and then it asks Do you want to convert this report to the latest RDLC format? I hit ok and it seems fine. This error happens on all the reports. The upgraded one or the one I never opend in VS 2013. I also upgraded from Report Viewer 2008 to Report Viewer 2010.  I have tried to add the Web.config suggestions in the error. I tried both entries and I have also tried each entry individually. Nothing seems to fix this. Everything else on the Web Site works fine.

Anyone got any suggestions? Do I need to upgrade Report Viewer to a later version? I am willing to try anything to get this to work. Thanks.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Looking in **my** VS 2013 project that uses report viewer, I'm using this report viewer NuGet package (as seen in the packages.config file):

```
<package id="MicrosoftReportViewerWebForms" version="11.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Then in my web.config, I have these two relevant section:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Finally, I had to install ReportViewer on the server. That involved both `ReportViewer.msi` and `SQLSysClrTypes.msi`. Unfortunately, though I still have both on my machine, I don't know exactly the URLs for downloading them.

For ReportViewer, I've tried the [Report Viewer 2012 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747) from Microsoft, but it's not a binary match to what I have. Still, that seems like it's probably right and mine's just outdated. I'd start with that.

For SQLSysClrTypes.msi, it's basically the same situation. You can get it from the [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 SP1 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580), but it's not exactly a match for what I used. Again, hopefully it's just been updated.

Comment: I have tried all of that with no luck. Though one thing I should have mentioned is I am testing this locally with IIS Express so I have decided to create test website on my IIS server so see if that if the problem.

Comment: I had to go away from this for a while (we had the web site running with .Net 2.0 still) since more urgent things came up. I finally figured it out. It was the last thing you would expect. There old code was using a CSS class for styling on the reportviewer.  Once I replaced that class the error went away. I had other issues with the report pages after that (like I had to take the code in the Page_Load and put it in the OnInit method because otherwise the loading of the report would go on forever) but everything is working now.